# How to remove edit icons in the Wagtail CMS nav menu if editing is limited through assigning a group?

Tags: wagtail

In my Wagtail CMS (v.2.1.1) I have created a group with limited access to editing pages. This works wonderfully, though the edit icon (pen) is still shown in the side menu of the wagtail admin. Clicking on it for deactivated user results correctly in a '403 Forbidden', but it would be great to be able to not display those icons in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open bug as of Wagtail 2.1.1: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4660

Comment: How could I fix this? Is there a way to overwrite some parts of the js to overcome this problem, or utilize one of the hooks of the menu construction?

Comment: I don't have a fix for this, sorry - if I did, I would have already contributed it back to Wagtail and closed the issue.